# Bitbucket pipeline script didn't change the file when pushing to server on Heroku

Tags: git, docker, heroku, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have this file for pipelines configuration `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`

```
# This script depends on two environment variables to be set in Bitbucket Pipelines
# 1. $HEROKU_API_KEY - Local environment var that contains your Heroku account's API key
# 2. $HEROKU_STAGING - Local environment var that contains your staging app name in Heroku
# 3. $HEROKU_PRODUCTION - Local environment var that contains your production app name in Heroku

 image: node:14

 # Doing a full clone to be able to push back to Heroku.
 clone:
   depth: full

 pipelines:
   branches:
     # When code is pushed to the staging branch it is deployed automatically to the staging environment.
     staging:
       - step:
           name: "Instalasi Server"
           caches:
            - node
           script:
            - npm install
            - chmod +x install.sh
            - ./install.sh
            - cat .env
            - git push -f https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_STAGING.git staging:master
```

I tried to copy `.env.bitbucket` to `.env` files, included in `install.sh`.

`install.sh`

```
apt-get update && apt-get install nano
mv ./.env.bitbucket ./.env
```

structur folder

[image]

.env.bitbucket

```
PORT=3500
NODE_ENV=development
DEBUG=testrolling:*
DB_HOST=<host name>
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=<database name>
DB_USERNAME=<database username>
DB_PASSWORD=<database password>
JWT_AUTH=<auth name>
JWT_EXPIRE=10m
```

.env

```
PORT=3500
NODE_ENV=development
DEBUG=testrolling:*
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=test_rolling
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=
JWT_AUTH=test_rolling_glory
JWT_EXPIRE=10m
```

I tried to replace `.env` files with `.env.bitbucket`, as you can see in this image below its working just fine. i tried to run `cat .env` and seen the env has changed, just like the `.env.bitbucket`.

[image]

But when i tried to running it on heroku, the `.env` still using the old ones. just like shown below.

[image]

How to fix the `.env` files that i push to heroku apps through bitbucket pipeline used the new `.env` ?

https://www.zionandzion.com/setting-up-continuous-deployment-with-bitbucket-and-heroku/

Comment: `git push` sends *existing commits*. Unless some of your scripts make *new* commits, you haven't done anything with the existing commits, so they'll still have the same stuff in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally got the answer.
I just need to add `git commit` and `git add` to my bitbutcket pipeline yml to make it works.

Before:

```
# This script depends on two environment variables to be set in Bitbucket Pipelines
# 1. $HEROKU_API_KEY - Local environment var that contains your Heroku account's API key
# 2. $HEROKU_STAGING - Local environment var that contains your staging app name in Heroku
# 3. $HEROKU_PRODUCTION - Local environment var that contains your production app name in Heroku

 image: node:14

 # Doing a full clone to be able to push back to Heroku.
 clone:
   depth: full

 pipelines:
   branches:
     # When code is pushed to the staging branch it is deployed automatically to the staging environment.
     staging:
       - step:
           name: "Instalasi Server"
           caches:
            - node
           script:
            - npm install
            - chmod +x install.sh
            - ./install.sh
            - cat .env
            - git push -f https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_STAGING.git staging:master
```

After:

```
# This script depends on two environment variables to be set in Bitbucket Pipelines
# 1. $HEROKU_API_KEY - Local environment var that contains your Heroku account's API key
# 2. $HEROKU_STAGING - Local environment var that contains your staging app name in Heroku
# 3. $HEROKU_PRODUCTION - Local environment var that contains your production app name in Heroku

 image: node:14

 # Doing a full clone to be able to push back to Heroku.
 clone:
   depth: full

 pipelines:
   branches:
     # When code is pushed to the staging branch it is deployed automatically to the staging environment.
     staging:
       - step:
           name: "Instalasi Server"
           caches:
            - node
           script:
            - npm install
            - chmod +x install.sh
            - ./install.sh
            - cat .env
            - git status
            - git add . // add this
            - git commit -m 'change env' // add this
            - git push -f https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_STAGING.git staging:master
```